# Generating Random Dates

Tags: r, date

How can I generate a set of 12 random dates within a specific date range?

I thought the following would work:

```
 sample(as.Date(1999/01/01), as.Date(2000/01/01),12)
```

But the result looks like a random set of numbers?

Thank you

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`seq` has a method for class `Date` which works for this:

```
sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 12)
```

Comment: How can I then change the format of the output to be in a format such as 01/01/1999?

Comment: See `?format.Date`.  To produce this format, you want the format string `'%m/%d/%Y'` (or perhaps `'%d/%m/%Y'` -- for this reason I recommend against this format).

Answer (score 14):

Several ways:

1. Start with a single `Date` object, and just add result from `sample()`
2. Start with a sequence of `Date` objects, and `sample()` it.

Here is 1:

```
R> set.seed(42)   
R> res <- Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:10, 3))
R> res
[1] "2014-02-04" "2014-02-10" "2014-02-11"
R>
```

Answer (score 5):

To follow base R functions like `rnorm`, `rnbinom`, `runif` and others, I created the function `rdate` below to return random dates based on the [accepted answer of Matthew Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21502397/4575331).

The default range is the first and last day of the current year.

```
rdate <- function(x,
                  min = paste0(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-01-01'),
                  max = paste0(format(Sys.Date(), '%Y'), '-12-31'),
                  sort = TRUE) {

  dates <- sample(seq(as.Date(min), as.Date(max), by = "day"), x, replace = TRUE)
  if (sort == TRUE) {
    sort(dates)
  } else {
    dates
  }

}
```

As expected, it returns valid dates:

```
> class(rdate(12))
[1] "Date"
```

And the randomness check, generating a million dates from this year:

```
> hist(rdate(1000000), breaks = 'months')
```

[image: Histogram of rdate]

Answer (score 3):

```
td = as.Date('2000/01/01') - as.Date('1999/01/01')
as.Date('1999/01/01') + sample(0:td, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
generateRandomDate <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  random_days <- sample(0:(as.numeric(end_date - start_date)), 1)
  start_date + days(random_days)
}

> set.seed(0); sapply(1:12, function(x) generateRandomDate(ymd("2023-01-01"), ymd("2023-1-31")) ) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01")

[1] "2023-01-14" "2023-01-25" "2023-01-04" "2023-01-07" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-02" "2023-01-29" "2023-01-23" "2023-01-11" "2023-01-14" "2023-01-18" "2023-01-27"
```

Note the use of as.Date() and  `origin` parameter. Not sure why the code wont run without them...