# Why is method 1 faster than method 2?

Tags: r, performance

**My question:** I was debugging some code at work, running it block-by-block, when I realized a small block was taking an unusual amount of time. I killed it and made a minor (but logically equivalent) tweak, and it ran almost instantly. I would like to understand why. The following code is in R, however, I imagine the answer may not be specific to R, and may apply to most programming languages of a similar paradigm or 'method-of-compiling'?

**The code & information:**
Using R version 3.6.1
Libraries loaded: dplyr, knitr, DataExplorer, glue, zoo

old_df is data frame of 5653380 obs. of 91 variables.
field1 is a col of policy numbers with class "character". Not unique, each occurs many times.
date_col1 and date_col2 are columns with class "date".

Method 1:

```
    new_df <- old_df %>%
      group_by(field1) %>%
      mutate(checkfield = date_col1 - date_col2) %>%
      filter(checkfield < 0) %>%
      filter(row_number() == 1)
    old_df$filter <- ifelse(old_df$field1 %in% new_df$field1,1,0)
```

Method 2:

```r
    new_df <- old_df %>%
      group_by(field1) %>%
      filter(date_col1 < date_col2) %>%
      filter(row_number() == 1)
    old_df$filter <- ifelse(old_df$field1 %in% new_df$field1,1, 0)
```

As you can probably see, the intended output of both methods is to add a flag, "1", in the column "filter" for policy numbers where date_col1 < date_col2. I did not write method 1, and my goal in writing method 2 was to change it as little as possible while also making it faster, so please avoid spending too much time talking about problems with method 1 that are not related to why it is unbearably slower than method 2. Feel free to mention such things, but I would like the crux to be why method 1 was taking 20, 30 minutes etc. For example, I believe in method 1, the first filter call could be above the group_by call. This might increase speed by an unnoticeable amount. I am not too concerned about this.

**My thoughts:** Clearly method 2 might be a little faster because it avoids making the column "checkfield", but I dont think this is the issue, as I ran method 1 line by line, and it appears to be the line 'filter(checkfield < 0)' where things went awry. For testing, I defined two dates x,y and checked class(x-y) which returned "difftime". So in this filter call, we are comparing "difftime" to a "numeric". Perhaps this requires some type of type-juggling to make the comparison, where as method 2 compares a date object to a date object?

Let me know what you think! I am very curious about this.

Comment: can you benchmark/give us a timing comparison on `filter(date_col1 < date_col2)` vs. `filter(checkfield < 0)` to support your conjecture?  (See e.g. the `microbenchmark` package ...)

Comment: @BenBolker. Yes! I don't know about that, but I will read up on the benchmark documentation.

Comment: I actually prefer the `rbenchmark` package to `microbenchmark`, but `microbenchmark` seems to be more popular.  They will give roughly equivalent results.

Comment: by the way, I think `%>% head(1)` might be a *lot* faster than `%>% filter(row_number() == 1)` ... and you can probably do the last step with an appropriate join ...

Comment: Thank you for the info Ben. I will remove the first two block of text from the question and look into the benchmarking. I am still at work now, so it will probably be this evening that I return and edit with the benchmarking. I also like the advice about head(1).

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of the increased time is due to creating the new column. As you can see, `M1` and `M3` have similar times. Of course that difference of ~2 milliseconds between `M1` and `M3` will multiply based on the data size

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42)
n = 1e5
d = seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 10000, Sys.Date(), 1)
x = sample(d, n, TRUE)
y = sample(d, n, TRUE)
df1 = data.frame(x, y, id = sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))

microbenchmark(M1 = {
    df1 %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(chk = x - y) %>%
        filter(chk < 0) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1)
},
M2 = {
    df1 %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        filter(x < y) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1)
},
M3 = {
    df1 %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        mutate(chk = x - y) %>%
        filter(x < y) %>%
        filter(row_number() == 1)
})
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
#   M1 13.130673 13.405151 15.088266 14.096772 15.56080 22.636533   100
#   M2  5.931192  6.208457  6.564363  6.402879  6.71973  9.354252   100
#   M3 11.360640 11.607993 12.449220 12.001383 12.57732 18.260131   100
```

For the point about comparing `difftime` to `numeric`, there doesn't seem to be a lot of difference

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42)
n = 1e7
x = sample(d, n, TRUE)
y = sample(d, n, TRUE)
df1 = data.frame(x, y)
df1$difference = df1$x - df1$y

class(df1$difference)
#[1] "difftime"

microbenchmark(date_vs_date = {
    df1 %>% filter(x < y)
},
date_vs_numeric ={
    df1 %>% filter(difference < 0)
})
#Unit: milliseconds
#            expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    date_vs_date 177.1789 222.4112 243.6617 233.7221 244.2765 430.4273   100
# date_vs_numeric 181.6222 217.1121 251.6127 232.7213 249.8218 455.8285   100
```

Answer (score 1):

My explorations so far, with a simplified example and a slightly smaller data set (only a million rows and a minimal subset of columns) have the individual tests (`test_cf` for filtering on the `checkfield` variable, `test_lt` for filtering on the date comparison) taking about the same time, which both take about the same time as creating the checkfield column. Doing both at once (`comb`, creating and comparing) takes 2.5 x longer, not sure why.

Perhaps you can use this as a starting point for bisecting/benchmarking to find the culprit.

```
     test elapsed relative
2    comb   5.557    2.860
1 make_cf   1.943    1.000
4 test_cf   2.122    1.092
3 test_lt   2.109    1.085
```

I used `rbenchmark::benchmark()` because I prefer the output format: `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()` might be more accurate (but I would be surprised if it made a big difference).

### code

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 1e6 ## 5653380 in orig; reduce size for laziness
set.seed(101)
## sample random dates, following
##  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502332/generating-random-dates
f <- function(n)
    sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"),
           replace=TRUE,
           size=n)
dd <- tibble(
    date_col1=f(n),
    date_col2=f(n)
 ## set up checkfield so we can use it without creating it
) %>% mutate(cf=date_col1-date_col2)
```

Benchmark:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
    make_cf=dd %>% mutate(checkfield=date_col1-date_col2),
    comb=dd %>% mutate(checkfield=date_col1-date_col2) %>% filter(checkfield<0),
    test_lt=dd %>% filter(date_col1<date_col2),
    test_cf=dd %>% filter(cf<0),
    columns=c("test","elapsed","relative")
)
```