# Replace Values in Column with Random Sequence of Values

Tags: r, for-loop, random, indexing

I have a dataset like the one below but with many more rows and columns.

```
df <- data.frame(lat = c(19.3606, 19.2462, 19.3587),
                 long = c(-155.0684, -155.2582, -155.0274),
                 acq_date = c('2020-12-11','2020-12-11','2020-12-13')
)
```

I want replace the acq_date column values with a random date within a defined time range. I found some codes to create a random date ([Generating Random Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502332/generating-random-dates)) and to loop through rows ([For each row in an R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699046/for-each-row-in-an-r-dataframe)) but I am not seeing new dates populated in the dataframe. What am I missing here?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row <- df[i,]
  row$acq_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020/12/15'), as.Date('2021/01/30'), by="day"), 1)
}
```

Comment: You can generate the random date date vector of the proper length and then just assign `acq_date` directly to that.  e.g. `df$acq_date <- randomdates`  No loops required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are taking the row out of the dataframe, edit it, but don't put it back.

To get your code working, you can do

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df$acq_date[i] <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020/12/15'), as.Date('2021/01/30'), by="day"), 1)
}
```

But i would suggest creating the randomdates all at one via

```
randomDates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020/12/15'), as.Date('2021/01/30'), by="day"), nrow(df))
```

and then insert them into the df via

```
df$acq_date <- randomDates
```